# get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' Error

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to make a list from requests that users made. But, I am getting this error.
I don't know what I did wrong. Can you help me?

my views.py

```
class RequestUserList(ListAPIView):
    serializer = NewRequestHPSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        current_user = request.user
        user_id = current_user.id
        queryset_list = RequestHepatoPredict.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get(user_id)
        if query:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(status__icontains = query)
                ).distinct()
        return queryset_list
```

my serializer.py

```
class NewRequestHPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user_request = UserSerializer(read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = RequestHepatoPredict
        fields = ('date_created',
        'pacient_code',
        'number_tumor',
        'tumor_size',
        'tumor_volume',
        'biopsy_date',
        'hp_kit_number',
        'HCC',
        'HextraHep',
        'SAMPLE_NEEDLEBIOPSY',
        'status',
        'rejected_date',
        'user_request'        
        )
```

Comment: Remove the `request` argument from your `get_queryset` method, it is not passed as a arg when the method is called. The request can be access from the view itself `self.request`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are passing `get_queryset()` method with more params than it is originally built. Secondly, you are passing only one `Q` complex query. [According to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) the `Q` letter needs to be at least two since it is built to be used as `OR` or/and `AND` operator within a query.

Try this way:

```py
    def get_queryset(self):
        current_user = self.request.user
        # user_id = current_user.id
        queryset_list = RequestHepatoPredict.objects.all()
        user = self.request.user
        if query:
            queryset = queryset_list.filter(
                status__icontains = user
                ).distinct()
        # need to return "queryset" here..
        return queryset
```